# Como passar nome de campo de tabela mysql como parâmetro via PDO PARAM?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário define alguns critérios para que o sistema faça uma busca de dados em um banco de dados mysql. Entre os critérios, o usuário pode escolher duas opções de busca. Essas opções são dois campos da tabela desse banco de dados.

Os dados são enviados via POST e estou utilizando PDO para realizar a pesquisa com uma query sql.

```
$dataini = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data_ini', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dataend = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data_fim', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$dataInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dataini)->format('Y-m-d');
$dataFinal = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dataend)->format('Y-m-d');
$opdata = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'op_data', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$sql = "SELECT nome, setor FROM mytable WHERE :opdata BETWEEN :datainicial AND :datafinal ORDER BY :opdata DESC";

$res = $conecta->prepare($sql);
$res->bindParam(':datainicial', $dataInicial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res->bindParam(':datafinal', $dataFinal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res->bindParam(':opdata', $opdata, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res->execute();
```

No entanto não está dando certo. Qual é o modo correto de passar os nomes de campos de tabela como parâmetros em uma query mysql seguindo os critérios de segurança?

Comment: vc não pode marcar identificadores (nomes de colunas/tabelas) como binds apenas valores.

Comment: @rray, como posso passar os nomes das colunas de forma segura para a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match()` para definir quais caracteres são válidos para uma identificador (vulgo nome) isso difculta um ataque de sql injection.

Basicamente a expressão regular diz para procurar um ou mais caracteres que sejam letras, números ou underline.

```
$campo = 'campo_valido234';

if(preg_match('/^\w+$/i', $campo)){
   $sql = sprintf("SELECT nome, setor FROM mytable WHERE %s BETWEEN :datainicial AND :datafinal ORDER BY %s DESC", $campo, $campo);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo!